# pandoc: Error producing PDF with R Markdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, pandoc

When doing `pandoc mymarkdown.md -o mypdf.pdf` I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.279 ...e know that the element stored at \(x \lt

pandoc: Error producing PDF
```

I'm confused, as using pandoc with any other markdown file works for me. `l.279 ...e know that the element stored at \(x \lt` corresponds to a line in my `md` file. If I remove that line from the file, the error persists, giving a different line and so on.

Comment: I don't know the answer. But since you're in a hurry, my suggestion is copy all your code into a plain text editor (like notepad if you're on windows), then back into RStudio. This will wipe out any non ASCII characters. Then try it. You may also want to copy it into a new `Rmd` file, just in case the current one is saved with some odd encoding.

Comment: @user5783745 Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately copying it didn't seem to work and I get the same error.

Comment: What happens when `pandoc mymarkdown.md -o mypdf.pdf --latex-engine=xelatex`

Comment: That removes the `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ∩¼ü (U+FB01)` but I still get ```! Undefined control sequence.
l.279 ...e know that the element stored at \(x \lt

pandoc: Error producing PDF```

Comment: Sucks that I can't format that better. But `l.279 ...e know that the element stored at \(x \lt` is essentially a part of a line in my `md` file. If I remove that line, I get the same error except it points out a different line, and so on.

Comment: Is it possible to paste the code into your question? It will allow anyone to try it on their computer

Comment: Edited my question to fit the issue better. Are you asking for the actual markdown file? It's a bit large, but I could post on pastebin.

Comment: I would recommend posting it if you can, pastebin is good

Comment: @user5783745 https://pastebin.com/raw/dyEYAJH1

Comment: I see the same error. I'll try solve now

Comment: Unfortunately I have not been able to solve the issue. I tried a minimal `Rmd` with only some yaml at the start and a code chuck containing only `2 * 2` and still cannot get it to work. I tried the two tips [here](https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging), but no luck

Comment: I just solved the problem. There was a problem with many of the headings for some reason, so I just removed them. Also for some reason had to remove any math that used `$\gt$` or `$\lt$` (guess pandoc doesn't support this, even though my preview window did). Thanks a lot for your help though, I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

> Unicode character ∩¼ü (U+FB01)

It suggests there's a character that is cannot be converted correctly. If you're getting literally that error—with no visible character—then what's probably happening is that you have some sort of invisible or space Unicode character in your document. For instance, `option`+`space` on Mac will leave an invisible non-breaking space, which gives an error that looks like that.

What you can do is starting from an empty document, then add one paragraph at a time, until you find the problem, then try to "re-write" the problem part.

Comment: Actually entering `--latex-engine=xelatex` fixes the Unicode error for me. But I get `! Undefined control sequence.` instead, and it still wont produce the PDF. Problem also is that my document is fairly large, but it still might be doable so I guess that could be a last resort for me.